# We have an "apple dos" tag. Do we need an "apple prodos" tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The 8-bit Apple II had two disk operating systems, DOS and ProDOS.

Currently we have a specific tag for [apple-dos](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-dos) but no matching tag for ProDOS. The text of the apple-dos tag seems clear that it doesn't currently include ProDOS:

> for questions about the Apple DOS operating system used on the Apple
>   II series of microcomputers

We currently have [18 questions that mention ProDOS](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/search?q=prodos%20is%3Aquestion), it seems arbitrary whether those use the [apple-dos](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-dos) tag or not.

1. Should we add a [apple-prodos](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-prodos) tag? (or [pro-dos](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-dos) or some other variant...)
2. Should the current tag specifically cover both and have its text updated to clarify that?

Answer (score 2):

It would seem reasonable to have a separate tag for ProDOS. After all it was somewhat different from the original Apple ][ DOS and, from memory, it was more prevalent on the Apple /// than on the ][.

I would keep to our convention of keeping the manufacturer in the tag, so [apple-prodos](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-prodos) would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

While I can live with [Chenmunka's suggestion](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/892/6659), I still think it's *way* too early to do so. There is no real gain to separate between various DOS from Apple - wich DOS, Prodos as well as SOS are - GS/OS is a different beast - like GEOS.

By labelling with a too fine granularity tags again become less useful. Right now we have barely passed a dozend questions tagged [apple-dos](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-dos), splitting that up might do more harm than it adds clarity.

Personally I'd wait for passing like 100+ questions (and thereof 30+ specific to ProDos) before turning the generic [apple-dos](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-dos) tag covering all DOS type os into a specific for the DOS line.

Not to mention that a [apple-prodos](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-prodos) should, like an other, only be applied if the question is really related to ProDos, not just because ProDos is somehow mentioned as context.